# Using Modernizr to Polyfill CSS transitions

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr, html5boilerplate

I have the modernizr js installed as part of HTML5 Boilerplate, but I don't know how to use it. I created a CSS3 nav with some transitions. I know IE doesn't support them, but as I understand it, Modernizr can polyfill using js. Is that right? How do I do that? I don't know much js.

[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Cu8/5/)

Comment: If you don't know much js, as you say, then what is your basis for assessing the solutions in Modernizr or proposed by Addy Osmani? I know this doesn't help you solve your immediate problem, but a (greater) problem on the web is the large number of would-be experts and bloggers rushing to assist but providing not the best advice. If possible, make your app so that it can degrade to work well without transitions.

Comment: I don't know who Addy Odmani is. Basically, I am just muddling through it and learning as I go. It works fine without the transitions. It's just not as pretty. I was hoping there was a js solutions to make it prettier when the css transitions won't work.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Good solutions aren't that easy and bad solutions are horribly complex -- like Modernizr, jQuery, and the other blog.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the yepnope script to check if css3 transition is supported or not. For example like this:

```
yepnope({
  test : Modernizr.transition,
  yep  : '',
  nope : ['polyfillfortransition.js']
});
```

**Update**

Actually if you use jQuery, there's a plugin for this. You don't need to do the code above. This post by Addy Osmani will explain it better http://addyosmani.com/blog/css3transitions-jquery/. In that post he also explain the use of yepnope.

Comment: Where do I put this? I'm really new to this. I put this in between some `<script>` tags in the HTML right under where I put the modernizr script, but nothing happened. This is my website `    `http://dev.newfrequency.com/index.html` if it helps you to look.

Comment: ok my bad...that `polyfillfortransition.js` is actually a sample, you need to get the actual js first before using it. But let me explain a bit about the code. So that `yepnope` is a test coming with `modernizr`. It'll test if css transition is supported by your browser or not. If not than you need to call a JS that will do the polyfill for you. You need to put that code in your js, I'll suggest to put it at the end of your code, before closing `body` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Modernizr doesn't provide any polyfills for CSS3 features. It does provide a simple polyfill to enable styling of HTML5 elements in older browsers. Other than that, it is used mainly as a way to detect features by adding classnames to the html tag of the page.

So in your css, you can do something like

```
.borderradius .mydiv {
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Modernizer will have added the .borderradius classname to your page's html tag if your browser supports it...or you can use it in your js to selectively fallback to plugins and the like.